# Active X Control issue on Terminal Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, terminal-server, activex

I have a security camera system which can be viewed remotely via a web browser. It works excellent only with IE 6 and up and requires an ActiveX control "ERViewer.ocx". Some users require to view the cameras via Windows Terminal Server, but when they try to open the link to the DVR they get the prompt ti install the ActiveX and then the browser crashes when they try to install it.

I logged in as admin and got the same issue. I called the tech support of the DVR but they have no idea, in other words, the usual useless tech support.

Here is what I get in the error log

```
Faulting application iexplore.exe, version 7.0.6000.16735, faulting module   ERViewer.ocx,
version 1.6.0.8, fault address 0x000064d7.
```

I am sure it could be some kinda permission getting an ocx to run in IE.

What else can I tweak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The activeX does not support windows Server edition.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the terminal server in installation mode when you try to install the ActiveX as Administrator? If not; try.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the control is conflicting with the video stream in the terminal session.  Does it also happen if you log onto the console on that server?

Comment: yes. Same thing.